# Magento submit order backend functionality not works

Tags: magento, submit

Am using magento 1.7.
Submit order at back end is not working .If i disable  merge javascript submit order button is working but I receive"Shipping address selection is not applicable" error. If I enable merge javascript file submit order functionality not works

Answer (score 0):

If you have changed code in shipping method or you have put your custom code in shipping method then you need to check it once. it seems there is problem in your code.

Make sure also that jquery is not conflict with your code, if jquery is conflict then you need to fix that issue first.